# Read file and insert Json objects in mongo, in Ubuntu

Tags: python, json, mongodb, csv, insert

I want to read a JSON file and insert each document of it into mongodb in Python.

Code is:

```
#!flask/bin/python
import json;
import csv;
import bson;


from pymongo import MongoClient
#connect to database
c = MongoClient('localhost',27017)
db = c.wsn

nodeInfo = db.nodeInfo;
table = db.table;


limit = 0;
skip = 0;
results = [];


#To be able to read csv formated files, we will first have to import the
#csv module.
with open('data.csv', 'rb') as f:
reader = csv.reader(f)
obj = [];
for row in reader:
for field in row:
    print(field);
        nodeInfo.insert_one(field);


File data is like : 
{"name" : "A"}
{"name" : "B"}
{"name" : "C"}
```

I am getting this error:

> TypeError: document must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON, bson.raw_bson.RawBSONDocument, or a type that inherits from collections.MutableMapping

Comment: if I directly use : nodeInfo.insert_one({"name" : "A"}), It is working fine, but in loop field = {"name" : "x"} each time. and its not working in loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your input data does not look like `csv` at all, not sure why are you using `csv` module to read it.

It looks like you have JSON strings on every line of the file. Read the file line-by-line, load it with [`json.loads()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.loads) and insert:

```
import json

with open('input_file.txt', 'rb') as f:
    for row in f:
        nodeInfo.insert_one(json.loads(row))
```